# Screen Tearing/Lag in java

Tags: java, lag

Okay, so I've looked at countless threads trying to figure out a solution to this, and haven't found one yet.  In 3 games that I've attempted making using Java, I've been experiencing occasional lag/screen tearing.  When it occurs, my FPS appears to be the same, yet it's still lagging.  Here's my gameloop and render method that I'm using.

```
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / UPS;

    int frames = 0;
    int updates = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    double delta = 0;

    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;

        lastTime = now;

        while (delta >= 1) {
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
            render();
            frames++;
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
            lastTimer += 1000;
            System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + " | Updates: " + updates);
            frames = 0;
            updates = 0;
        }
    }
}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    do {

        do {

            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, screenSize.width + 10, screenSize.height + 10, null);
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
            if (getCurrentScreen() != null) {
                getCurrentScreen().render(g2);
            }

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

            g.dispose();
        } while (bs.contentsRestored());
        bs.show();

    } while (bs.contentsLost());
}
```

Anyone have any solution to this?  Thanks!

Comment: Using AWT or Swing to create a game is really painful, why don't you try a real game engine like libGDX or JMonkeyEngine ?

Comment: I've used libGDX and various other engines but for some reason I find it more entertaining to use swing vs another engine.

Comment: Writing more stuff from scratch and dealing with the ins and outs of Swing builds better confidence with Java, imo. Also causes more headaches - I do it this way too :D @Loafayyy - can you provide any visual examples of the screen tearing? A screencap or a GIF or somesuch? I'd recommend overriding the `paintComponent` of a `JPanel` to `getDrawGraphics` though.

Comment: The next time it happens, I'll try to get a visual.  Something unusual is that when I'm recording a video of the lag, it suddenly stops, but when I stop recording, it comes back.  I'll try switching to paintComponent and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried double buffering? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

Comment: Imo, the tearing can also come from the fact that you are using single buffering. You could try double buffering and see if the performance increases. The tearing should disappear at least..

Comment: I am already using triplebuffering, and have tried pageflipping.

Comment: @Gorb okay, so it occurred again, and I was able to capture it on my  phone (not sure if that's good enough for a visual, but there is a noticeable difference from when it was lagging to when it was not).  Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJk-LfhM79I&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Can't see the difference personally, though I appreciate I'm not there with the controls. I've implemented simple sprite movement with timed render updates (using `paintComponent`) and I experience no issues. Even added hit detection over the top. 60FPS stable. Might have another stab over the weekend, see if I can help.

Comment: I haven't used paintComponent many times, but how would you call paintComponent without a Graphics object?  (This is probably a stupid question xD)

Comment: Are you using any sleep calls or wait loops to achieve game loop timing?  If not, your loop may be hogging the CPU.